# Jenkins groovy file can't import another groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, fastlane

In simple form, I have 2 groovy files in the repo in /jenkins subfolder. File A.groovy and B.groovy. Inside A.groovy I have a load line

```
load(env.WORKSPACE + "@script/jenkins/B.groovy")
```

The problem is I get an error

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/JobName@script/jenkins/B.groovy
```

But as we see, overall looks like load function created kinda almost correct url. The point is my actual fetched repo, and particularly A.groovy is getting into the additional subfolder. I see that in the very beginning of the logs and can find locally there.

```
Checking out git ... into /Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/JobName@script/ecb7a9317b1ad672698830264d9e0ce2b9b6f330c043bb85f48623f3cdcab65e/jenkins/A.groovy
```

Tried to log whole `env` object using `echo sh(script: 'env|sort', returnStdout: true)` and there is no any property containing that subfolder name at all.

Why I am getting that extra ecb7a9317b1ad672693830224d9e0ce2b9b3f730c043bb85f48925f3cdcab65e subfolder and how can I either get rid of it or get it's name somehow to compose correct url for import?

Comment: Try `env.WORKSPACE` instead of pwd()

Comment: @daggett Tried just now. Same effect as pwd()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround (by searching the folder), but would like to find a better and native way.

Where `jenkins` in `-name 'jenkins'` is the subfolder name containing groovy scripts.

```
git_jenkins_folder = sh (
        script: "find \"" + WORKSPACE + "\"@script -type d -name 'jenkins'",
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()

utils = load("$git_jenkins_folder/Utils.groovy")
```

Which generates the correct working path like this.

```
/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/JobName@script/ecb7a9317b1ad672698830264d9e0ce2b9b6f330c043bb85f48623f3cdcab65e/jenkins
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the path you pass to `load`. The `env.WORKSPACE` does not end with `/`.

```
load("${env.WORKSPACE}/@script/jenkins/B.groovy")
```

Comment: Folder name with script looks like `Job Name@script`. There is no need to add `/` as it's a single folder name.